# How to get height and width of a popup menu in android?

Tags: java, android, android-menu, dimensions, popupmenu

I have a popup menu and I just want to get dimensions of it to use in my showCaseView for my guided tour. I could not find anywhere the way to determine these dimensions (height and width).

```
private void initPopUpMenu() {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(TimelineActivity.this, menuIcon);
    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_timeline, popupMenu.getMenu());
}
```

How to retrieve width and height from this structure? It's a simple menu resource with 5 items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to use `ListPopupWindow` instead of `PopupMenu` which has `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods to get its dimensions. However, if you really want to use `PopupMenu`, the possible tricky way is to use `Reflection` to access its internal `ListView`, because there is no method available in `PopupMenu` to access the content view.

**Usage:**

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = initPopUpMenu();
popupMenu.show();

ListView listView = getPopupMenuListView(popupMenu);

androidx.core.view.ViewKt.doOnLayout(listView, view -> {
    System.out.println("PopupMenu Size: " + view.getWidth() + " x " + view.getHeight());
    return null;
});
```

**Methods:**

```
private PopupMenu initPopUpMenu() {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(TimelineActivity.this, menuIcon);
    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_timeline, popupMenu.getMenu());
    return popupMenu;
}

private ListView getPopupMenuListView(PopupMenu popupMenu) {
    Method getMenuListViewMethod = null;
    try {
        getMenuListViewMethod = PopupMenu.class.getDeclaredMethod("getMenuListView");
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListView listView = null;
    if (getMenuListViewMethod != null) {
        getMenuListViewMethod.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            listView = (ListView) getMenuListViewMethod.invoke(popupMenu);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return listView;
}
```

**build.gradle:**

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
}
```

**Result:**

> I/System.out: PopupMenu Size: 539 x 660

Comment: Importante to notice that if You need these values on future point in code you'll need to call it inside the doOnLayout method, otherwise it may no have been called yet

Comment: Exactly, you are right. Because outside of the doOnLayout we don't know when the list view is laid out, so its dimensions are not achievable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom layout with `PopupWindow` and then measure it

```
val popupWindow = PopupWindow(context)
popupWindow.contentView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.my_popup, null).apply {
    measure(
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    )
    measuredWidth// <-- here is width
    measuredHeight// <-- here is height
}
```